How can I check scopes in oapi-codegen middleware?
I'm completely new to oapi-codegen and its generated code.
I tried to generate echo, as well as chi-server code.
I defined, in my openapi specification security like this:
  /itworks:
    get:
      summary: Just a test endpoint
      description: |
        A test endpoint which will return some info
      operationId: itworks_get
      security:
        - bearerAuth: ["statistics"]  # JWT
        - apiKey: ["statistics"]    # API-Key
      responses:
        "200":
          $ref: "#/components/responses/200_OK_message"
        "401":
          $ref: "#/components/responses/401_Unauthorized"

The generated code looks like this:
// ItworksGet operation middleware
func (siw *ServerInterfaceWrapper) ItworksGet(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := r.Context()

    ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, BearerAuthScopes, []string{"statistics"})

    ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, ApiKeyScopes, []string{"statistics"})

    handler := http.Handler(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        siw.Handler.ItworksGet(w, r)
    }))

    for _, middleware := range siw.HandlerMiddlewares {
        handler = middleware(handler)
    }

    handler.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
}

and my middleware like this (just the apikey part to keep it short:
func AuthMiddleware(apiKey string) func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            authHeader := r.Header.Get("Authorization")
            apiKeyHeader := r.Header.Get("ApiKey")

            if apiKeyHeader == apiKey {
                fmt.Printf("API Key found %s\n", generated.ApiKeyScopes)
                requiredScopes := r.Context().Value(generated.CSApiKeyScopes)
                if requiredScopes != nil {
                    fmt.Printf("API Key Scopes: %v\n", requiredScopes)
                }
                next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
                return
            }

So here I just wanted to print out the required scopes, assuming that they were set in the context.
Unfortunately they are not set.
I need some help in understanding how this works. How can I test in the middleware the scopes required to access my endpoint?
Update Do I have to check the scopes in each handler myself?

Okay. Seems I can solve my issue with ServerOptions.
